# flash[:notice] displaying extra character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a strange issue where an extra/random character ("0") is being displayed with my flash[:notice]. I can't figure out where it's coming from.

**Controller:**

```
  def edit
    @subject = Subject.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @subject = Subject.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @subject.update_attributes(strong_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Subject has been updated'
      redirect_to action: 'show', id: @subject.id
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def delete
    @subject = Subject.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  private

  def strong_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
  end
```

**View:**

```
   = if !flash[:notice].blank?
  .notice
    = flash[:notice]
    %h2 Update subject
    = form_for :subject, :url => {action: 'update', id: @subject.id} do |f|
      = f.label :name, 'Name:'
      = f.text_field :name
      = f.label :position, 'Position:'
      = f.text_field :position
      = f.label :visible, 'Visible:'
      = f.text_field :visible
      = f.submit 'Update Subject'


 %h2
   Are you sure you want to delete the subject - #{@subject.name}
   = link_to 'Yes, delete!', action: 'destroy', id: @subject.id
```

Comment: Can you try changing `= if !flash[:notice].blank?` to `- if !flash[:notice].blank?`?

Comment: You're correct! Thank you. Still getting use to the HAML syntax. :)

Comment: I wasn't sure hence comment (I will paste it as answer now), I was striken by something similar few days ago ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as it turned out the answer is: change 'loud' haml `= if !flash[:notice].blank?` to 'silent' `- if !flash[:notice].blank?`.